# Stage3D causes fullscreen (Stage)Video to lag/jitter

Tags: actionscript-3, video, netstream, stage3d

I'm having some serious problems with flash at the moment. I have a swf loaded that uses Stage3D, displaying 3D content. When I overlay a video player, on full screen size, it will cause massive lag/jitter in the video content. The video content is loaded locally so there is no streaming to take into account. This only happens on some machines but considering the project this cannot be neglected.

I have since recoded my project to remove any form of loading i was doing with a Loader and just directly put the file path into the netstream and have then attached the netstream to StageVideo. But the problem still persists and I am at my wits end. I even set Stage3D to invisible during video playback.

It's a complete horror to debug because it's simply not a problem on my machine, but out of 10 people 4 of them have reported this problem and we can't release our product like this.

Any help to resolve this would be greatly valued and appreciated.

Regards,

Kevin

Comment: can you try to create a simple example reproducing this behaviour and upload it somewhere?

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?42oi96nllfiwf0r - Granted, it's meant to be a standalone projector. Included are some flv's and a loader.swf for the 3D. This is just a quick mockup for the people with problems to test

Answer (score 0):

Well as StageVideo is using GPU like Stage3D does. So I guess those two stages are interrupting each other processing on GPU (especially on older video cards).

So my answer is to try to stop that video while you are working on Stage3D.

Comment: I only started using StageVideo after I found the jitter in a regular Video/Netstream as a way of solving the problem. Sadly it didn't work. How does one disable stage3D or pause it?